# Laravel artisan migrate ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, windows, laravel-4

I trying to load data to the database via PHP artisan migrate command in laravel 4. But the terminal throws the following error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","me
```

ssage":"Call to a member function increments() on a non-object","file":"C:\xamp
p\htdocs\lartut\lartut\app\database\migrations\2014_04_17_072025_create-u
sers-table.php","line":15}}

Don't what's causing this error. Can Someone please help me with this.

Comment: In "2014_04_17_072025_create-users-table.php" at line 15 you're trying to call a method (`increments()`) on a variable that's not an object. Start debugging there.

Comment: @Maerlyn increments() was the one given in the laravel docs. I don't know what wrong with that.

Comment: The problem is not with increments, but with the variable you're calling it on.

Comment: @Maerlyn oh ya just now noticed it. this is that line 15 $table->increments('id'); Why does it calls 'id' a non-object

Comment: Nope, `$table` is a non-object.

Comment: @Maerlyn don't know exactly what I did, but its working now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my issue.

I used

```
 php artisan migrate:install
```

before migrating the table. And it worked..........